# Adding multiple feature classes from TOC as input by ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder

I am tasked to create a tool using ModelBuilder. The tool requires input of multiple feature classes that are added in the Table of Contents of ArcMap.

The user will then be able to select multiple feature classes from the drop down list (all feature classes available in the TOC should be listed) from on the tool interface.

Which tool or tools should I use?

Comment: You might want to look into model parameters. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002w0000003z000000.

I'm not sure how easy this would be in model builder, but definitely possible with python. What have you tried?

Comment: Further to @GISKid recommendation and that you have tagged your question as Python [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Integrating_scripts_within_a_model/002w0000006n000000/) is how to wire a python script into toolbox, note the multi-value property of the input parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Build your model and make sure it works. Use Feature Layer instead of feature class as the input of your model. to do so, simply drag the layers to your model. after you successfully run the model, close it and

1. right click the model in the Catalog Window >   Properties
2. Go go parameters tab and click the plus button to add a new parameter
3. select the parameter you want to use as the input of your model.

[image: add model parameter]

Answer (score -1):

It  looks like you are looking for the "select data" tool in the model builder.
This tool, when marked as a parameter, gives u a list type GUI.

For more information:
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Examples_of_using_Model_Only_tools_in_ModelBuilder/00400000001m000000/ESRI_SECTION1_D2DFA72326C54E05B1CB2DAC24FCBCFC/